# @ManyToMany duplicate entries

Tags: java, duplicates, many-to-many, persist

I have a problem with persisting. I have a Meal class in which is a list of Products. In Product class is a list of Meals -- @ManyToMany relation.

When I try to save it Compiler want to save every product, but then products are duplicated in my DB. 
How I can indicate that the products are already there?

Here is my code

```
@Entity
public class Meal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
            CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    private List<Product> foodList = new ArrayList<>();

    @NaturalId
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String mealName;

    private Integer servingWeightGrams = 0;
    private Integer servingQty = 0;
    private Double nfCalories = 0d;
    private Double nfTotalFat = 0d;
    ...

@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "foodList")
    private List<Meal> meals = new ArrayList<>();

    @Column(unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String foodName;
    ...
```

```
@Service
public class MealManager {

    MealService mealService;
    ProductService productService;

    @Autowired
    public MealManager(MealService mealService, ProductService productService)
    {
        this.mealService = mealService;
        this.productService = productService;
    }

    public Meal saveMeal(List<Food> foodList, String mealName){

        Meal newMeal = new Meal();
        newMeal.setMealName(mealName);

        List<Product> productList = parseFoodToProduct(foodList);

        productList.stream().forEach(y -> newMeal.getFoodList().add(y));

        for(Product food : productList) {

            newMeal.setNfCalories(newMeal.getNfCalories() + food.getNfCalories());
            newMeal.setNfCholesterol(newMeal.getNfCholesterol() + food.getNfCholesterol());
            newMeal.setNfDietaryFiber(newMeal.getNfDietaryFiber() + food.getNfDietaryFiber());
            newMeal.setNfP(newMeal.getNfP() + food.getNfP());
            newMeal.setNfPotassium(newMeal.getNfPotassium() + food.getNfPotassium());
            newMeal.setNfProtein(newMeal.getNfProtein() + food.getNfProtein());
            newMeal.setNfSaturatedFat(newMeal.getNfSaturatedFat() + food.getNfSaturatedFat());
            newMeal.setNfSodium(newMeal.getNfSodium() + food.getNfSodium());
            newMeal.setNfSugars(newMeal.getNfSugars() + food.getNfSugars());
            newMeal.setNfTotalCarbohydrate(newMeal.getNfTotalCarbohydrate() + food.getNfTotalCarbohydrate());
            newMeal.setNfTotalFat(newMeal.getNfTotalFat() + food.getNfTotalFat());
            newMeal.setServingWeightGrams(newMeal.getServingWeightGrams() + food.getServingWeightGrams());

           /*if(! productService.ifExists(food.getFoodName())) */  productService.save(food);
        }

        return mealService.save(newMeal);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to invoke `productService.save(food)` at the end of your for loop in `MealManager`.

You can try adding some utility methods in the `Meal` class, to keep the relationship in sync, as described in [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-naturalid-business-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

So, in your `Meal` class, you can add a method like

```
public void addProduct(Product product) {
   foodList.add(product);
   product.getMeals().add(this);
}
```

and call this method inside the for loop in `MealManager`, instead of simply calling `newMeal.getFoodList().add(y)`.

Because you have `CascadeType.MERGE` defined for `ManyToMany`, the relationship will then be synchronized in both entities.

Other observations:

- I can't see what the `parseFoodToProduct` method is doing, but assuming it retrieves the necessary products from the db, you should mark the `saveMeal` method as `@Transactional`
- you're looping 2 times through the `productList` in `saveMeal`... once with `stream().forEach()` and once with the enhanced for... I'd keep only the enhanced for in this context